# How many japa malas does one need?

Tags: japamala

There are so many japa malas for so many different sadhanas.
Is it recommended to use the same mala for multiple sadhanas?
Else how many does a regular person keeps with him/her ?

Answer (score 1):

For Chanting Hare Krishna Mahamantra you need a Tulsi Mala but if you are not dixit you can practice Chanting on Neem Mala or any other Mala but not Tulsi Mala because it's for the Dixit and those who follows 4 regulative principles Devotees only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).